# Next JS - SSR with nested component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, server-side-rendering

I need to create navigation in Layout with data from API and display it on certain pages.

Layout is not in the pages folder, I can't use the getStaticProps and getServerSideProps methods.
At the same time, I would like the navigation to be created on the server side and be immediately on the page for SEO.

Now I'm getting data using the getStaticProps method on pages where this navigation is needed, and everything works, but the navigation component is loaded additionally.

Couldn't find an answer anywhere on how to do this. There must be some option...
Thanx.

Comment: Hi, and welcome to StackOverflow! Sorry, but in its current state, your question might get downvoted or closed. Please create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) when asking so people can help you better.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of getting categories from pageProps in _app.js, I called useEfefct, changed it to pageProps, now everything is fine.